# jQuery CouchDB - filter keys for view

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am using the javascript library which comes bundled with couchdb to query the database.

[On a side note here is a good overview of the functionality it provides, with a lot of good examples.](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/)

It is possible to filter the results from a view by specifying the key values to return. This is easily done with a query string ([documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API)) but how do I do it with the javascript API?

This is how I am doing it with a query string (please note that the JSON portion of the key-value-pair would need to be HTML encoded):

```
http://localhost:5984/MyDocuments/_design/MyDesign/_view/MyView?key=["Michael","2011-08-01"]
```

And this is my javascript without the query string portion of the filtering process applied.

```
$.couch.db("MyDocuments").view("MyDesign/MyView", {
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
    },
    reduce: false
});
```

Comment: If you ever tire of jquery.couchdb, I am a fan of (my own) request.jquery, which is a very concise, simple HTTP and Couch client. https://github.com/iriscouch/request_jquery. And I have not tried it heavily yet but Nano has the goal of being the simplest possible CouchDB client: small, simple, just what you need, that sort of thing. https://github.com/dscape/nano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured this one out while writing the question. It was reasonably easy but there are not a lot of examples online so therefore feel the need to take this opportunity to provide an example.

```
$.couch.db("MyDocuments").view("MyDesign/MyView", {
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
    },
    key: ['Michael','2011-08-02'],
    reduce: false
});
```

The "key" section is what you are looking for :)